# Leaflet zoom change to points

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet 1.0.3. Its a simple map having a geojson layer and no basemap at all. I want to change zoom level step from 1 to 0.1 or 0.25 so that when user scroll or press zoom in or zoom out, map zoom level should change e.g. from 6 to 6.1 instead of 7.

I tried zoom snap but it only change the value from integer to decimal but the step value remain the same (i.e. 1)

Comment: See `zoomDelta` option: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#map-option

Comment: yes tried that as well. Dont works

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve desired effect of setting zoom change step level to `0.1` for all zoom change operations (keyboard, zoom control, mouse scroll), you have to set three map options: `zoomSnap`, `zoomDelta` and `wheelPxPerZoomLevel`:

- with `zoomSnap: 0.1` map option you allow intermediate zoom levels;
- with `zoomDelta: 0.1`map option you set step level for keyboard and zoom control changes;
- with `wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 600` map option you set desired scroll zoom step. Why value of `600`? This option sets how many scroll pixels (as reported by `L.DomEvent.getWheelDelta`) mean a change of one full zoom level. Since default value is `60` for one full level change, value `600` is one tenth of that.

.